# Do I need a join?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 3 tables: products, products_description, products_to_categories

Here is my sql:

```
SELECT `products`.`products_model`, 
       `products_description`.`products_name` 
FROM   products, 
       products_description, 
       products_to_categories 
WHERE  `products`.`products_id` = `products_description`.`products_id` = 
                                         `products_to_categories`. `products_id` 
       AND `products_to_categories`.`categories_id` <> '91' 
ORDER  BY `products`.`products_model` DESC
```

all three tables have products_id as the primary key and I am trying to link all three based on that. I think I need a join because I cant seem to make all three just be equal in one statement?

Comment: If all three have the productid as primary, why not use one table only?

Comment: @stryba: one reason would be to avoid nullable columns where, say, a product doesn't need to have description.

Comment: @onedaywhen thanks, for the answer, even though I am aware of some reasons. My intention was to make the OP reevaluate and check his design.

Comment: @stryba: The relationships may be changed later (and even now it may not be strict `1:1`). The `product_id` may also not be the Primary key in all tables. A product may have more than one (`1:n`) descriptions or no (`1:0..1`) descriptions or may belong to many categories (`1:n`).

Comment: @ypercube, did you read my answer to onedaywhen?

Comment: @stryba: Oh, sorry, I thought that was someone else's comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do it with a JOIN but if you wanna use a Where statement that's fine, but you'll have to use **AND** to make it happen

```
SELECT `products`.`products_model`, `products_description`.`products_name`
FROM products, products_description, products_to_categories
WHERE `products`.`products_id` =  `products_description`.`products_id` 
   AND `products`.`products_id`= `products_to_categories`.`products_id` 
   AND `products_to_categories`.`categories_id` <> '91' 
ORDER BY `products`.`products_model` DESC
```

Comment: Thanks that's the simplest. I actually tried this and was getting duplicate products so I thought I was wrong but I just realized I have duplicate products in many cateogries.

Comment: @Sackling glad I can help, this is essentially a JOIN that you are doing here.

Answer (score 1):

```
select p.`products_model`,
    pd.`products_name`
from products p
inner join products_description pd on p.`products_id` = pd.`products_id`
inner join products_to_categories pc on p.`products_id` = pc.`products_id`
where pc.`categories_id` <> '91'
order by p.`products_model` desc
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
SELECT products_model, products_name
  FROM products
       NATURAL JOIN products_description
       NATURAL JOIN products_to_categories;
```

Answer (score 0):

The more modern `JOIN` is generally preferred to the old implicit join syntax anyway.  It presents a much more readable picture of how the tables relate, and allows a clearer `WHERE` clause by including only the actual limiting condition in `WHERE`.

```
SELECT 
  `products`.`products_model`,
  `products_description`.`products_name`
FROM 
  products
  JOIN products_description ON products.product_id = products_description.product_id
  JOIN products_to_categories ON products.product_id = products_to_categories.product_id
WHERE  `products_to_categories`.`categories_id` <> '91' 
ORDER BY `products`.`products_model` DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

Try not to use commas in your FROM clause. It's a hold-over from a much older version of the sql standard, and not really considered a good practice any more. Just about everywhere you use `TableA,TableB` syntax right now you should learn to use `TableA INNER JOIN TableB ON` instead.

In this case, though, you could get away with it like this:

```
SELECT `products`.`products_model`, `products_description`.`products_name`
FROM products, products_description, products_to_categories
WHERE `products`.`products_id` =  `products_description`.`products_id` 
    AND `products`.`products_id` = `products_to_categories`. `products_id` 
    AND `products_to_categories`.`categories_id` <> '91' 
ORDER BY `products`.`products_model` DESC
```

But again, you really should learn to write that like this:

```
SELECT `products`.`products_model`, `products_description`.`products_name`
FROM products
INNER JOIN products_description ON products.products_id = `products_description`.`products_id`
INNER JOIN `products_to_categories` ON `products_to_categories`.`products_id` = `products`.`products_id`
WHERE `products_to_categories`.`categories_id` <> '91' 
ORDER BY `products`.`products_model` DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    SELECT `products`.`products_model`, `products_description`.`products_name`
```

FROM products, products_description, products_to_categories
WHERE `products`.`products_id` =  `products_description`.`products_id` AND  `products_to_categories`. `products_id`=`products`.`products_id` AND `products_description`.`products_id` = `products_to_categories`. `products_id`
 `products_to_categories`. `products_id` AND `products_to_categories`.`categories_id` <> '91' 
ORDER BY `products`.`products_model` DESC

try this i think it work better like your query